# How to find first business day of month in Java?

Tags: java, date

Let's say I have the current day, the next day, and the previous day. And I want to write a method that finds the first business day of the month by doing logical operations on them. For example, the first working day of November 2021 starts on the 4th, because the 3rd of the month has no working days due to holidays. In short, we need to write a program that takes into account non-working days and finds the first working day of each month.

Comment: What do mean by first business day? Like a non-holiday day? Including public holidays? Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: For example, I want to write a program that finds the first business day of each month. Let's say the first working day of November starts from 3, because days 1 and 2 are not working days, so 3 coincides.

Comment: I guess you need a api for holidays

Comment: @Gurkanİlleez  It is necessary to write a program showing the first working day of the month, provided that the holidays are taken into account.

Comment: @Gurkanİlleez probably yes if present.

Comment: How do you know what is the working day and what is not? By Day of Week? Example, some countries start their working week on Sunday (US, for instance) some countries start working on Monday (Russia), some never work on Saturdays (Israel)...  By some list of holidays specific to your country?

Comment: @MarkBramnik yes it is

Comment: the source code comes with this (so you can ignore its for tomcat), http://windsolarhybridaustralia.x10.mx/httpoutputtools-tomcat-java.html   but in essence the workings of time like that can be too national or traditional if you want public holidays e.r.c. You probably could build an array to screen dates, nb it is possible to return day of year with java.time and week and quarter, but if you really need , a custom java.util.calendar look at Calendar.Builder (note: jvm runtime TZ update files)

Comment: Use [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html) and specifically `java.time.LocalDate`. Without knowing your holiday API I can’t tell you more than this.

Comment: I guess there is no internal means in the java lang to tell which day of a month is the first business one. That depends on the country and the year - is regulated with laws - so there is no sense in putting it into java itself even as a part of Locale. It's called "производственный календарь" in Russia - factory calendar (in Russia we check this calendar in Consultant Plus). You need to use some third party JAR as a dependency or call some server via HTTP sending as a param your country and month and year in your request (mey need paid subscription).

Answer (score 3):

Well, there is no standard Java library to get the dates of the holidays. That would be too localized, because holidays heavily depend on your country and region (except for widely known holidays, such as Christmas or Easter).

You must rely on some external source, for instance a holiday API. Once you have the holidays, you could easily get the first business day of a month.

In the code below, I've hardcoded the holidays as a `Set` of `LocalDate`s. I also assumed that business days are from Monday to Friday.

```java
public static Optional<LocalDate> firstBusinessDayOfMonth(YearMonth month) {

    // I've hardcoded the holidays as LocalDates
    // and put them in a Set
    final Set<LocalDate> holidays = Set.of(
        LocalDate.of(2021, 11, 1),
        LocalDate.of(2021, 11, 2),
        LocalDate.of(2021, 11, 3)
    );
    // For the sake of efficiency, I also put the business days into a Set.
    // In general, a Set has a better lookup speed than a List.
    final Set<DayOfWeek> businessDays = EnumSet.of(
        MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY
    );

    return

        // All dates of the month
        month.atDay(1).datesUntil(month.plusMonths(1).atDay(1))

            // Retain all business days. Use static imports from
            // java.time.DayOfWeek.*
            .filter(date -> businessDays.contains(date.getDayOfWeek()))

            // Retain only dates not present in our holidays list
            .filter(date -> !holidays.contains(date))

            // Get the first
            .findFirst();
}
```

To get the first business day of the current month, use `firstBusinessDayOfMonth(YearMonth.now())`.

Note that this method returns an `Optional`, because it could theoretically be the case that there is no business day within the whole month.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the answers and help, but this is what I wanted.

Here, in my isOperateDay variable, they say that the data they have already sent me from the other server is 1 business day, not 0 business day. What I just wanted to do was to check if the values between yesterday and today are the first working day.
As you can see, I'm taking yesterday's month and comparing it to today's month, if yesterday's month is different, it means it was the previous month and my current day's month is counted as the first working day.

```
@Data
class ST_XF_DWH {
    private LocalDateTime previousDate;
    private LocalDateTime currentDate;
    private int isOperateDate;
}

    public void isFirstWorkDay(ST_XF_DWH st_xf_dwh) {

        LocalDateTime previousDate = st_xf_dwh.getPreviousDate();

        LocalDateTime currentDate = st_xf_dwh.getCurrentDate();

        if (previousDate.getMonth() != currentDate.getMonth() && st_xf_dwh.getIsOperateDate() == 1) {
            System.out.println("Is First Work Day" + st_xf_dwh.getCurrentDate());
        } else {
            System.out.println(st_xf_dwh.getCurrentDate() + "is not First Work Day");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Do you mean the return value is boolean? @OleV.V.

Comment: If so, that's how it was done since it's a simple experiment at the moment.

Comment: I would declare `isOperateDate` a `boolean` (not an `int`). Sorry that I was unclear.

Comment: it is not my rule, it is rule, where provider declare.